# In wave optics when light ray interfere constructively then from where the value of $n$ in "$n$$\lambda$ " starts (from 0 or from 1)

Tags: optics, waves, interference

[image: Question is]
[image: Solution is]

In the given solution why we have taken value of $n$ =1.
Why don't we take $n$=0.

On taking $n$=0, it gives a negative value of $h$. I think this is the reason we have taken $n$=1 instead of $n$=0.

But what if $h$ comes positive in any other question, can we then be able to put $n$=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't 'start' anywhere. Any integer, whether positive or negative, will lead to identical interference (at least, for purely monochromatic sources, and absent other geometrical factors). Here they are picking out a single choice for convenience only - it's a contrived example to begin with.